# Any way to limit geocoding to city or zip?

Tags: contacts

For privacy purposes in making a public member map - I'd like to set up the geocoding not by the full address, but by the city or zipcode. Is there a way to do this without creating a custom geocoder?

Thanks!
Harold

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry no, You will need to create a custom geocoder.

Creating a custom geocoder should be as easy as copying the current one you want to imitate, renaming it (to avoid confusion and keeping things clear for your successors) and dropping it in your custom php directory in CRM/Utils/Geocode/ (since u dont want to modify the core directories)

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. I had to use sql to delete all the current geo_code_1 and geo_code_2 fields in the civicrm_address table, as batch updating was limited to 100.

Thanks for providing the location of the php code. Going one step deeper to offer privacy - when I click on the people icons on the map - it shows the full address. I researched and found the Mapping Providers are at templates/CRM/Contact/Form/Task/Map. When I copied and edited - it shows up as a selection - but when I search contacts, the "Map Contact" no longer shows up. Any hints? Or the right place to ask? Thanks!

Comment: 1. Since this is a Q&A format, lets stick to one Q per thread.  Please post your follow-on privacy question as another question. 2. Can you also mark this thread as answered.